# Angular update warning

Tags: angular, warnings, npm-install

I just updated my angular project. Everything seems to be fine except I get the following warnings:

```
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.2 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1 < 3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@8.0.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.4 <3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.0.2 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.4 < 3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I went into my `package.json` and under `devDependencies` i had the following:

```
"typescript": "~3.5.1",
```

So I changed it to:

```
"typescript": "^3.4.0",
```

I then deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm install`, but the warnings are still there. The command `npm ls typescript` returns the following:

```
intergun@0.0.0 C:\Users\jbra\Programs\intergun
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.2
  `-- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.800.2
    `-- typescript@3.4.4
```

So it looks like it is indeed using typescript version 3.4.4. which should satisfy the requirements in the warnings.

What is the problem here? Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: `^3.4.0` would still include 3.5.x, try `~3.4.0`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that worked. Guess I misunderstood the meaning of `^`. Bonus question: Isn't it weird that I used typescript 3.5.1 for Angular 7, but now that I have updated to Angular 8 it requires a lower version of typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use should use ~ or none.
when you use the tilde ~ it will match the most recent patch version (the third number) for the specified minor version (the second number).
~3.4.0 will match all 3.4.x versions.

when you use the caret ^ it matches the most recent minor version (the second number) for the specified major version (the first number).
that is you will be using ^3.x.x

[Here's a visual explanation of the concepts:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vgxE.png)